# Splunk - display top values for only certain fields

Tags: splunk

So, let's just say I have a field for items at a store.  I have a field called price and a field called color.  If I want to display the top values for each price, I can do that easily by searching for "**top price**".  Suppose I want to filter and make a table by showing all of the top values for the blue items only. The percentages calculated by the top command still include all possible colors of items, I just only want the blue items to show up in the table.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

try this

base search
| top price
| search color="blue"
| table price color

Comment: This does not return any results :(

Comment: My actual query: index="myindex" rating="bad" | top source_ip | search rating="bad" | table source_ip rating

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should [work](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/top):

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp rating="bad" color="blue" price=*
| top price by color rating
```